# How to display an array under certain conditions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have to display how many array I have in a group.
The array are associated with a group by their ID.
When the group is -1, the group doesn't exist and the 0 is forbidden.
So when the array has a group > 0 it has a group associate.

To display the array card, I use a v-for:

```
<div class="overview" v-for="group in groups" :key="group.id">
```

and to display

It misses the method that returns the number in the correct group.
I tried this but it doesn't work

```
array(group) {
    http.get('array/group/' + group.id)
        .then( result => {
            if ( result.length > 0) {
                 console.log(result);
                 this.array= result.length;
            } else this.array= '0'
        })
        .catch(error => {console.error(error);
    });
    return this.array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You function returns something outside the asynchronous get.

```
function numberOfFixtures(group) {
    return http.get('fixture/group/' + group.id)
    .then( result => result.length);
}
```

Comment: do you know How display an object promise?

Comment: like `numberOfFixture({id:44}).then( size => console.log(size) );`

Comment: Yes you can console log , but I want display it in HTML

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that fetching happens asynchronously in javascript - This means that your return statement is executed long before your network request is completed. Rather then returning the count straightaway, you can return a promise which is resolved to the number of fixtures once the network request is completed:

```
numberOfFixtures(group) {
    // Returning a promise, not a value
    return http.get('fixture/group/' + group.id)
        .then( result => {
            return result.length > 0
                ? result.length
                : '0';
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    });
}
```

When you want to get the number of fixtures now:

```
numberOfFixtures(group).then((fixtureCount) => {
    // Do something with fixture count
}
```

Comment: Thanks but so now when I want display it , How can I do ?

Comment: Hi Sebastian - I have not used Vue specifically, but I believe this page will be of interest to you: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html - Particularly the watchers section. You might also check out https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html